# Minimum to know about Websphere 6

Tags: websphere

I'm unemployed and I have a job interview tomorrow where knowledge about Websphere 5.x and Websphere 6.x is required. I only use Tomcat and Glassfish.

What is the strict minimum to know about Websphere?  They will ask me if I have ever used it and I will say no but I would like to have a few things to say in order to lower the impact of not knowing it.

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Maybe to spell its name correctly ;). Just kidding, the title is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides the obvious (its file structure, deploying an app, etc.) maybe you can surprise the interviewer by mentioning [some features version 6 incorporated](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/0606_petersonr/0606_petersonr.html). I found really useful to read changelogs to understand the features of a software version

Answer (score 1):

You need to know just enough to be able to rip it out and replace it :-)